# Allow mulitple values not working in SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a report that uses a multi value parameter when ran in SQL pulls data without issue. When applied in a Stored Procedure and processed through SSRS with "Allow Multi Values" enabled when selecting multiple values the report returns no data. Like other users if I select a single value the report will return data.

I have done some homework and tried increasing my parameter value but this did not help either.

Please see below for my query. The parameter in question is the @material parameter.

```
With Zone as 
(Select 
 name,
 id 
 From datex_Footprint.LocationContainersView
 Where 
 typename IN ('Zone', 'Area') 
)
SELECT inv.projectId,
       inv.projectName,
       inv.materialLookupCode,
       inv.materialDescription,
       CASE
           WHEN sn.id IS NULL
           THEN inv.totalPackagedAmount
           ELSE 1
       END AS totalPackagedAmount,
       inv.licensePlateLookupCode,
      z.name WarehouseZone,
       inv.locationName,
       sn.id serialNumberId,
       sn.lookupCode,
       udf.SerialRef1,
       udf.SerialRef2,
       udf.SerialRef3,
       udf.SerialRef4,
       udf.SerialRef5
FROM datex_footprint.InventoryDetailedViewByLicensePlateLot inv
     LEFT OUTER JOIN datex_footprint.SerialNumbers sn ON sn.lotId = inv.lotId
                                                         AND sn.licensePlateId = inv.licensePlateId
                                                         AND sn.archived = 'False'
     LEFT OUTER JOIN datex_footprint.SerialNumbersUdfs udf ON udf.id = sn.id
    INNER JOIN datex_footprint.LocationContainersView lcv ON lcv.id = inv.locationId
     INNER JOIN datex_footprint.locationcontainers LC ON LC.id = lcv.id
 INNER JOIN Zone z ON z.id = LC.parentid
WHERE inv.projectName IN(@projectName)
     AND inv.materialLookupCode IN(@material)
AND (inv.locationName IN(@locationName)
OR (@locationName IS NULL));
```

Comment: Are you passing @material to a stored procedure parameter?

Comment: Yes. Though i think Alan Schofield hit the nail on the head. I think dropping the SP and running the query directly within the datset will correct the issue. Again will report back on Tuesday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have to use a stored procedure then the easiest way of solving this would be to put this code directly into your dataset. It will then work as you expect, SSRS will convert you multi-value parameter into a comma separated list and inject it into the SQL statement.

If you have to use the stored proc then you will need to do all the conversion yourself including splitting the values up inside your stored proc. There are plenty of examples out there on how to do this such as http://www.codeulike.com/2012/03/ssrs-multi-value-parameters-with-less.html

Personally, I always put dataset code directly in the dataset query, it's more convenient, means less objects on the SQL server but could be less secure.

Comment: Thanks i will try this on Tuesday when i return back to work and will report back.

Comment: Dropping it as a Stored Procedure and running the query directly as a Dataset resolved my issue. Thank you for your assistance.